# Error Reading a Text File in Java

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

I have to read from a file, so made:

```
cod_order (int)
cod_cliente (int)
cod_pizza (int)
num_pizza (int)
cod_pizza
num_pizza
...
$FINE
```

here is an example:

```
1
1107
02
1
01
5
03
2
$FINE
```

I created this method to read from this text file:

```
private void loadOrdini(String fname){

    try{

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));

        String cod_ordine = reader.readLine();
        while(cod_ordine!=null){

            String cod_cliente=reader.readLine();

            Cliente cl=listaclienti.get(Integer.parseInt(cod_cliente));

            String cod_pizza=reader.readLine();
            while(!cod_pizza.equals("$FINE")){

                String n_pizze=reader.readLine();

                Ordine ord = new Ordine(Integer.parseInt(cod_pizza),Integer.parseInt(n_pizze));

                cl.getListaOrdini().put(Integer.parseInt(cod_ordine), ord);

                cod_pizza=reader.readLine();

            }

            cod_ordine=reader.readLine();
        }

    }
    catch(IOException ioe){

        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

the problem is the method load into the HashMap listaordini only the numbers `03` and `2` while the numbers before aren't considerer.why?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Cliente{

private String name;
private String address;

private Map<Integer,Ordine> listaordini;

public Cliente(String n,String addr){

    name=n;
    address=addr;

    listaordini=new HashMap<Integer,Ordine>();
}

public String getName(){

    return name;
}

public String getAddr(){

    return address;
}

public Map<Integer,Ordine> getListaOrdini(){

    return listaordini;
}

public String toString(){

    String temp="";

    temp+="Nome Cliente: "+name;
    temp+="\nIndirizzo: "+address;

    return temp;
}

}
```

even after this suggets the problem remain the same

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, your map `listaordini` is supposed to map your order IDs to pizza orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the other answers have missed the point: you want a mapping from order IDs to pizzas.

The problem is, a map (such as a HashMap) must have a unique mapping for each key. What that means is, you can only map a **single** `Ordine` to the order ID, a map doesn't support having multiple `Ordine`s for the same order ID.

There's a couple of ways around this. You could make a new object that contains a list of `Orders` and put that into the map, or you could change your map to map an order ID to a `List` of orders.

For example, doing it the second way you would have:

```
// To create your map:
Map<Integer, List<Ordine>> listaordini = new HashMap<Integer, List<Ordine>>( );



// To add an order to it:
Ordine ord = new Ordine(Integer.parseInt(cod_pizza),Integer.parseInt(n_pizze));

List<Ordine> ordineList = cl.getListaOrdini( ).get(Integer.parseInt(cod_ordine));
if (ordineList == null)
{
    ordineList = new ArrayList<Ordine>( );
    cl.getListaOrdini( ).put(Integer.parseInt(cod_ordine), ordineList);
}

ordineList.add(ord);
```

Comment: thanks you that's was the problem. I was trying to map many order with a unique key and this was impossible for the nature of the map.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call reader.readLine(), you are moving to the next line in the file.

Thus, when you call

```
Cliente cl=listaclienti.get(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
```

You are actually moving to the next line and getting 02 when you meant to parse 1107.

Comment: Yes, @Mazzy, you've already read the `cod_cliente` line containing "1107" when you do `String cod_cliente=reader.readLine();` - then you try to read it *again*, but you're actually reading the "02" just as Meursault points out. Do `listaclienti.get(cod_cliente)` since you already have that value.

Answer (score 0):

You've called `readLine()` too many times:

```
    String cod_ordine = reader.readLine();
    while(cod_ordine!=null){

        String cod_cliente=reader.readLine();

        Cliente cl=listaclienti.get(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
```

You populate `cod_ordine` with the first `readLine()` call.

You populate `cod_cliente` with the second `readLine()` call.

You create the client object with the *third* `readLine()` call -- using what *should* have been a `cod_pizza` value as a client value.

Try this:

```
    String cod_ordine = reader.readLine();
    while(cod_ordine!=null){

        String cod_cliente=reader.readLine();

        Cliente cl=listaclienti.get(Integer.parseInt(cod_cliente));
```

Comment: ok I fix it but the problem remain the same.it loads me only the last two values of the file

Answer (score 0):

```
cl.getListaOrdini().put(Integer.parseInt(cod_ordine), ord);
```

because all the value you put into this map use the same key, which is `cod_ordine`, so every time you call this method, you replace the old `ordine` with new one, that's why you only have last record.

Comment: I'm not convinced.When I create the object I put it and save it into the hashmap